# Azure SQL database duplicate the database schema

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure SQL database that contains two tables `Product` and `Order` that are saved in the `dbo` schema. I want to write a C# program that will add new schema and duplicate the same tables definition that exist in `dbo`.

Existing:

```
dbo.Product
dbo.Order
```

Run the C# program to create a new schema for client1 then two tables will be added to the data base and the list of tables become:

```
dbo.Product
dbo.Order
client1.Product
client1.Order
```

Would you please let me know how I can do that with c#?

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere in there.

Comment: I have seen a database that had a separate schema for each customer and it was a nightmare.  As a DBA I beg you not to do this.  Put the data in one table (for each object) with a ClientID column.

Comment: Thank you Dave for your advise, I will update this in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure that receives two input parameters:

1. name of the schema to be duplicated
2. name of the new schema

Then you can invoke this procedure from your c# program.

Inside the procedure you can build a dynamic statement querying SQLServer's system table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

The idea is to:

- create the new schema
- clone source tables from the old schema to the new schema
- then delete all rows from the tables in the new schema

Please not that if you have foreign keys you'll have to manage them.

Here is a sample to start from:

```
create procedure p_clone_schema(
  @source_schema nvarchar(50),   
  @new_schema    nvarchar(50)   
)as
begin
    --check if destination schema already exists
    if not exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA where schema_name = @new_schema)
    begin
        --create new schema
        declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE SCHEMA ' + QUOTENAME(@new_schema) 
        exec(@sql)
        set @sql = ''

        --build statement to copy tables in the new shema and then truncate them
        select @sql = CONCAT
                    (
                    @sql ,  'select * into ' , QUOTENAME(@new_schema) , '.' , QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
                    , ' from ' , QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) , '.' , QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) 
                    , ' truncate table ' , QUOTENAME(@new_schema) , '.' , QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                    )
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        where TABLE_SCHEMA = @source_schema 
            and TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

        exec(@sql)
    end
end
```